# subscribe button youtube with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm creating a bot with python & selenium to subscribe to a list of channels. The problem I'm having is that sometimes its already subscribed and errors. I'm therefore trying to make a function to check if its already subscribed with `is_displayed()` but it what i've tried isn't working.

The error message I receive is

> :Message: no such element: unable to locate element ( https://prnt.sc/i54an3 )

And my code is:

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//paper-button[@subscribed=""]').is_displayed() & driver.find_element_by_xpath('//paper-button[@aria-label="Se désabonner de cette chaîne"]').is_displayed():
do what i want
else:
do what i want
```

Comment: (Aside from the question) In Python `&` is the Bitwise AND operator. You should use `and` instead.

Comment: thanks but its same :(

Comment: Which locale is `Se désabonner de cette chaîne`? How would it read in English? Can you update the exact `Manual Steps` which you are trying to `Automate`?

Comment: I can't think of any reason you would want to create such a bot that would be in line with Youtube's TOS

Answer (score 0):

When I want to check for elements that only sometimes will show up, I do a find_elements... first and if the length of the list is greater than 0 then I know it is there.

```
my_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('some class name')

if len(my_list) > 0:

    Element exists so now do something
```

Your code will generate an error because Selenium will search for the element first before executing is_displayed() if that element does not exist.